# When using UITextField Settext method can't receive UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

I want custom `UITextFiled` input view, at custom view listen textField value change.

when I use `self.textField.text = @"demo";`

`UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` was not called,but
 `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` got called,

How can I get  `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textBeginEdit:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Notifications are not sent when the text field is updated via code. This is by design.

Comment: @lintao when you are setting self.textField.text = @"demo"; in code that means know when this will happen. Then why not just call textChanged: function directly there. Why notification is required?

Comment: @aman.sood I Don't want to  have UITextField reference in custom view,this is my code https://github.com/NSObjects/OMGEmojiKeyboard, i hope UITextField value change control send button disable or enabel

Answer (score 0):

Assign your ViewController as the UITextField's delegate.  Make sure your controller conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, then implement these delegate methods in your controller.

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad]
      self.textField.delegate = self;
}
```

// implement these methods

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
- textFieldDidBeginEditing:
- textFieldShouldEndEditing:
- textFieldDidEndEditing:

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I'm suggesting an alternative

Comment: It's not an alternate. You have misunderstood the question.